# How to make ID2D1SolidColorBrush replace and not blend colors when drawing?

Tags: c++, direct2d

I have a small game in which terrain is displayed with lines. An example "boulder":

[image]

When drawing an object the lines are drawn first and then I draw circles on the ends of the lines to smooth out the corners. This is the relevant code for how I create the brushes and draw:

```cpp
// bi.color is of type D2D1::ColorF
bi.color = D2D1::ColorF::White;
bi.color.a = 1.0f - transparency;

ID2D1SolidColorBrush* pBrush = NULL;
p_RT->CreateSolidColorBrush(
    bi.color,
    &pBrush
);

p_RT->DrawLine(
    D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(spos.x), static_cast<FLOAT>(spos.y)),
    D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(epos.x), static_cast<FLOAT>(epos.y)),
    pBrush,
    bi.size
);

D2D1_ELLIPSE ellipse;
ellipse.point.x = cpos.x;
ellipse.point.y = cpos.y;
ellipse.radiusX = width;
ellipse.radiusY = height;

p_RT->FillEllipse(
    ellipse,
    pBrush
);
```

The problem arises when the boulder is fading away and the `color.a` value becomes less than 1. Every draw function is using the same brush but the colors end up combining and produce this result:

[image]

**Is there a way to have the brush replace colors instead of blending them?** If yes, how?

The Microsoft docs have no mention of this. `ID2D1StrokeStyle*` argument in `DrawLine` function might be what I need to change, but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of drawing line by line you should create polygon object by using [`ID2D1GeometrySink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1geometrysink-addline) and draw it using `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawGeometry` providing `ID2D1PathGeometry`.

The DrawGeometry method accepts `D2D1_STROKE_STYLE_PROPERTIES` where you can define line joins you need, e.g. `D2D1_LINE_JOIN_ROUND`

Comment: I thought about that, but is it worth recreating the geometry object every frame?

Comment: Ideally you should cache that ID2D1PathGeometry object so it will not be tessellated each time. But you can create it when needed too. That should not be more  expensive than those lines and ellipsis drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `ID2D1DeviceContext`, you can switch blending mode with `SetPrimitiveBlend()`. But I think better solution is to draw whole polygon at once - you'll need to create geometry, add your lines to it, and then do `DrawGeometry()` with line join behavior you want. Join mode is specified via ID2D1StrokeStyle.